# Inserting list from view to Model in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been returning a list from my controller to the view;

```
public ActionResult Raffle_Conso(int conso = 0)
{
    return View(db.Users_Info.Where(s=>s.by_name_rank == null).OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(conso));
}
```

In my view, I looped it and put in an input field.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertRafflers","Events", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    { 
        <input type="text" name="rafflers_name" value="@item.rafflers_name" />
    }
    <input type="submit"  value="Insert list" />}
}
```

It displayed the list. I like to ask if how would it be possible to insert the list from the view to the database via controller? 
Any idea is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please post the code of your view... i mean the code inside of your loop in the view

Comment: What is the model for `Users_Info`? Your creating manual inputs with no relationship to your model, no binding and won't post back to a collection because they are not correctly named with indexers

Comment: Users_Info is actually a view coming from the database.

Comment: Your need to show the model and its properties (at least a few of them). You also need to create your controls properly using html helpers inside a `for` loop (not `foreach`) or using a custom `EditorTempate` for typeof `Users_Info` (and `Users_Info` is not a view, its a model!)

Comment: read this post and you'll get this working - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: I mean, queried it from the view table in database and get the specific id. After that, the list will then be inserted into another table since views can combine many table.

Answer (score 0):

Your control `name` needs to be named like an array...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertRafflers","Events", FormMethod.Post))
{
    var textIndex = 0;
    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    { 
        @<input type="text" name="rafflers_name[@textIndex]" value="@item.rafflers_name" />
        textIndex += 1;
    }
    <input type="submit"  value="Insert list" />}
}
```

Comment: Then tell your `Html.BeginForm` the correct action to use.

Comment: I mean how to insert it to database using the list from the form

Comment: That depends entirely on what database technology you are using (`System.Data`, `Entity Framework`?).